# Closing wx.Dialog from event handler within a panel by clicking a button in another class

Tags: event-handling, wxpython

I can't get the buttons events (Save, Close) in the following ButtonsPanel class to fire their event handlers in the AddModFormContractors class.

The following command:

```
pnlButtons = ButtonsPanel(parent=self.frm_pnl)
```

is passing a PANEL as the parent of the ButtonsPanel, and that fails the binding in runtime, if I bind to "parent.onClose". Trying to pass just "self" renders nothing on the frame at all. Running it as in the code below throws an exception that onClose is missing the second (event) argument.

How can I get this to work, please?

```
class ButtonsPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        btnSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        okBtn = wx.Button(self, label="Save")
        okBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, AddModFormContractors.onSaveRecord)
        btnSizer.Add(okBtn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        cancelBtn = wx.Button(self, label="Close")
        cancelBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, AddModFormContractors.onClose)
        btnSizer.Add(cancelBtn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(btnSizer)
        self.Layout()



class AddModFormContractors(wx.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, targetObject, row=None, titlePrefix="Add", titleLabel="Record", addRecord=True):

        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None, title="{} {}".format(titlePrefix, titleLabel), size=(730, -1))

        self.targetObject = targetObject
        self.addRecord = addRecord
        self.selectedRow = row

        ... DOING RECORD STUFF HERE ...

        #Construct the form
        self.frm_pnl = wx.Panel(self)
        self.frm_pnl.BackgroundColour = (235, 230, 220)  # BEIGE

        font = wx.Font(12, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        lbl = wx.StaticText(self.frm_pnl, label="{} {}".format(titlePrefix, titleLabel))
        lbl.SetFont(font)

        pnlCompany = CompanyPanel(parent=self.frm_pnl, record=recordToUpdate)
        pnlRecord = RecordPanel(parent=self.frm_pnl, record=recordToUpdate)
        pnlButtons = ButtonsPanel(parent=self.frm_pnl)

        self.frmPnl_vertSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        ... BUILDING THE SIZER HERE ...

        self.frmPnl_vertSizer.Layout()
        self.frm_pnl.SetSizer(self.frmPnl_vertSizer)


        wx.CallAfter(self.SetFrameSize)

    def onClose(self, event):

        print("Closing")
        self.Destroy()


    def onSaveRecord(self, event=None):
        if self.Validate():
            if self.addRecord:
                dictRecordValues = getValuesFromForm(self, self.olv_dict)
                forms_controller.insertRecord(self.targetObject, dictRecordValues)
            else:
                dictRecordValues = getValuesFromForm(self, self.olv_dict, False)
                forms_controller.updateRecordById(self.targetObject, self.recordId, dictRecordValues)
            # self.titleTxt.SetFocus()

            self.Destroy()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up passing the event handler's class object as an argument to the container holding the buttons (buttonsPanel), and there I could reference the event handler in the parent frame. Argument name passed here is dialogFrame:

```
class ButtonsPanel(wx.Panel):
    """ Just a button panel """

    def __init__(self, parent, dialogFrame):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.dialogFrame = dialogFrame

        """
        Since the events affect another class frame(dialog), we pass the dialogFrame to this function.
        We demonstrate two binding/invokation ways here:
        okBtn - biding to the handler in dialogFrame class.
        cancelBtn - binding to this class handler, closing the frame by referencing frameDialog
        """

        btnSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        okBtn = wx.Button(self, label="Save")
        okBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.dialogFrame.onSaveRecord)
        btnSizer.Add(okBtn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.cancelBtn = wx.Button(self, label="Close")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onClose)
        btnSizer.Add(self.cancelBtn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(btnSizer)
        self.Layout()

    def onClose(self, event):
        """
        Cancel the dialog
        """
        print("Closing")
        self.dialogFrame.Destroy()
```